# Pandas dataframe plot not sharing x axis label?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I have two subplots, but I would like both of them to share the same common Xlabel. Each subplot is coming from a separate dataframe. Problem is that, the xlabels are not being shared eventhough I used `sharex=True`. Each subplot is having it's own xlabel, from the dataframe column name.

Code:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=True)


df1.plot.line(ax=ax[0],x='X',y='Y',linestyle='--',
                 marker='s', color='tab:orange',legend=False, sharex=True)


df2.plot.line(ax=ax[1],x='X',y='Y',linestyle='--',
                  marker='s', color='tab:blue',legend=False, sharex=True)

plt.xlabel("Epoch")
plt.show()
```

Comment: Please add some test data to make the code reproducible. Are the X values integers, floats, strings, dates, categorical, ...? Please also add an image of the obtained plot. Are you using the latest pandas and matplotlib versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you expecting this kind of result:
[image]

If yes, you need to correct:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(1,2, sharex=True)
```

by:

```
fig,ax = plt.subplots(2,1, sharex=True)
```

Comment: ok yeah, makes sense